# JSP EL: dynamic creation of property name

Tags: java, jsp, el

I am trying to dynamically generate content using JSP.

I have a `<c:forEach>` loop within which I dynamically create bean accessors. The skeleton resembles this:

```
<c:forEach var="type" items="${bean.positionTypes}">
    ${bean.table}  // append 'type' to the "table" property
</c:forEach>
```

My problem is: I want to change the `${bean.table}` based on the type. For example, if the types were `{"Janitor", "Chef}`, I want to produce:

```
${bean.tableJanitor}
${bean.tableChef}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the brace notation `[]` to access bean properties using a dynamic key.

```
${bean[property]}
```

So, based on your example:

```
<c:forEach var="type" items="${bean.positionTypes}">
    <c:set var="property" value="table${type}" />
    ${bean[property]}
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: This works for a property. What about a property inside a property (i.e., bean.someProperty.someField)? I did manage to get that to work, but I am not sure if my solution follows the best practices. @BalusC is my solution (see my answer below) alright or is there a best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access a complex field in a dynamic way, you could do this:

```
<h:outputText value="#{someOtherBean.invokeELGetter('#{bean.'.concat('someProperty.field').concat('}'))}" />
```

And implement the invokeELGetter in your SomeOtherBean class:

```
public Object invokeELGetter(String el) {
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ELContext elContext = facesContext.getELContext();
    ExpressionFactory expressionFactory = facesContext.getApplication().getExpressionFactory();
    ValueExpression exp = expressionFactory.createValueExpression(elContext, el, Object.class);
    return exp.getValue(elContext);
}
```

Note that this requires EL 2.2 (Tomcat 7 for those who use Tomcat).